# Angular Single url used for all routing?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Here is my apps home page url: `http://localhost:4200/`
Whenever the user selects a next button a new screen loads with a new url similar to the examples shown below:

`http://localhost:4200/screen/static/text/1/0`

`http://localhost:4200/screen/activity/click-and-reveal/1/1`

`http://localhost:4200/screen/activity/click-and-reveal/3/2`
and so on

I would really like the url to display a single value something like http://MyProjectName ..... as i think it looks rather unprofessional to have the url looking the way it is looking currently.

Any help as to how i could accomplish this would be greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL won't change if you use the navigation option [SkipLocationChange](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#skipLocationChange) on your links.

```html
<a routerLink="/somePath" skipLocationChange>Settings</a>
```

Or in code behind:

```js
this.router.navigate(['/somePath'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

Comment: This appears to be pointing me towards a solution, I will be attempting to solve this today. If this works, ill be sure to accept your answer as a solution thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly, thank you again for your help @fridoo

Answer (score 0):

Their are few ways to achieve it:-

1. Redux
2. Shared Observable

Comment: Thanks i will look into this when i get a chance :)